# Match groups of elements in a list to all elements of a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have table UserSkills with secondary keys UserId, SkillId, SkillLevlelId. This table has relation UserSkill - Users many-to-one. Then I have dictionary with SkillId and SkillLevelId. I want to take users which UserSkills accord Dictionary.
Please help me to write Linq to Entity.
My Db scheme https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85460129/quest.jpg

Here is a better description of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Looking at your scheme it seems that UserInfoes does not join to users.  Where is the FK?

Comment: Unless `UserID` and `UserInfoID` are the same, in which case you should name them the same (and probably put them in the same table.)

Comment: UserInfo table isn't interesting, i need users by userskills params accord my dictionary skillId-skillLevelId

Comment: FK is ok. I use code first with EF and FK added by attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fired up LinqPad (you should get it at linqpad.com it makes these things easy).

You can find the full solution at https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/5811644

The interesting part of the code follows below:

**How this works**

First we group by user id.  Then we take each group and join to the two keys in the dictionary.  If the result of the join has the same count as the dictionary then we know it matches the dictionary and we select the userID as an element in the result list.

```
var result = userSkills.AsEnumerable()
      .GroupBy(userRow => userRow.Field<int>("UserId"))
      .Where(userGroup => userGroup
                .Join(skillList,
                      user => new { sID = user.Field<int>("SkillId"), slID = user.Field<int>("SkillLevelId") },
                      skill => new { sID = skill.Key, slID = skill.Value },
                      (user, skill) => true).Count() == skillList.Count())
      .Select(match => new { userID = match.Key });
```

Which produced this output:

[image]

Comment: `public IList<User> GetUsersBySkills(IDictionary<int, int> skills)
        {
            using (var db = new DataContext())
           {
                var result = from userSkill in db.UserSkills
                             join skill in skills on new{userSkill.UserSkillId, userSkill.SkillLevelId} equals
                                 new {skill.Key, skill.Value}
                            select userSkill;               

            }`

Comment: It's great idea to join with dictionary, i try this. bu i have problem with type when join. And i need one more join with users table to selec users in result

Comment: Dictionary has SkillId as key and SkillLevelId as Value

Comment: Because i create template on UI to find users by parameters and save this template in this dictionary. Thanks a lot for your help